# How to Integrate box-ui-element Box.com ContentPreview in a React js Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, box

i want to make component which accept token and file id and show a file preview . i am using box.com
it has ui element called ContentPreview but how integrate it is not clear from the doc. There no other article or blog wasn't seen related to it.

used box-ui-element package

```
import React from 'react';
import ContentPreview from 'box-ui-elements/es/elements/content-preview';

const ContentPreviewComponent = ({ fileId, token, language }) => {
  return (
    <ContentPreview
      fileId={fileId}
      token={token}
      language={language}
    />
  );
};

export default ContentPreviewComponent;
```

this was the component i made but react is throwing some error contentPreview import does not exist in package
and  please share how to create a box app to save file and preview it in the react app